# Converting ob_get_clean results in PHP

Tags: php

I am working on an existing php site, and it has an export page which spits out data and is saved into text documents. (txt & xtg)

```
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

The problem I'm trying to fix is the encoding of the output, apparently the charcters are not displaying correctly. I'm pretty sure the database is in the correct UTF-8 format.

The issues show up like this `La FÃ©dÃ©ration`

I tried the following, but it didn't work - the output is still wrong - any ideas ?

```
$output = mb_convert_encoding($output, "UTF-8");
```

this is the rest of the relevant code

```
// Ouput file.
// Set DOS line endings for Quark 6
file_put_contents( "/var/www/vhosts/artsdb.net/httpdocs/export/" . $type . "/" . $filename . ".xtg.txt", str_replace( array( "\n", "\r\n\r\n" ), array( "\r\n", "\r\n" ), $output ) );

echo "Exporting " . str_replace( "_", " ", $filename ) . " ($type) complete.\n\n";
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: If that's how the data is displayed form the database, then it means that either the data is wrong (e.g. if the data was inserted by sending UTF-8 over a Latin1 connection, but retrieved using a UTF-8 connection), or your page isn't set to display as UTF-8.

Comment: You said "I'm pretty sure the database is in the correct UTF-8 format.". Are you completely sure or not? Did you check the db to see if the values are being stored correctly?

Comment: I'm just having a double check now

Comment: Hmm it is actually wrong in the database eg fÃ¼r Musik, so not sure what to do here now - the collation is set at utf8_general_ci. Is there a way to sweep through the table and convert ? I'm assumming that the data was orginally like this - and at some point the collation has been changed to be correct, while the data remains wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the data displays properly on the site itself and the browser shows your pages are UTF-8.

To troubleshoot this, I would first remove any encoding conversion and try to open the text file in a web browser to eliminate any issues with how you're looking at the file and to confirm it is indeed coming out in UTF-8.

If the browser above shows the content in the text file is not utf-8, try calling utf8_encode on the $output before writing it to file.

Comment: The tables & collation seem to be set at utf8, and the data which is shown on the website seems to be fine (that uses htmlentitites it seems) however the export to text file just shows the odd characters still. utf8_encode doesn't seem to affect this either?