# UTF-8 incorrect with PHP ob_get_clean/include_once + htmlentities?

Tags: php, utf-8

I guess this is similar to [Converting ob_get_clean results in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772002/converting-ob-get-clean-results-in-php), but that answer didn't help me - so I have made a minimal "working" example of my problem. There are three files in this test:

**`utftest.txt`**

```
øæå jeść ясть
```

**`utftempl.txt`**

```
<?php echo htmlentities( $content ); ?>
```

**`utftest.php`**

```
<?php

  echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() . "\r\n\r\n";

  $content = file_get_contents("utftest.txt");
  $templateFile = "utftempl.txt";
  ob_start();
  include_once($templateFile);
  $file_output = ob_get_clean();
  print_r($file_output);

?>
```

I'm assuming `utftest.txt` is properly encoded as UTF-8, otherwise here is the hexdump:

```
$ hexdump -C utftest.txt 
00000000  c3 b8 c3 a6 c3 a5 20 6a  65 c5 9b c4 87 20 d1 8f  |...... je.... ..|
00000010  d1 81 d1 82 d1 8c 0a                              |.......|
00000017
```

I run this test with the `php-cli` interpreter, with `php utftest.php`. On my local PC, I get this output in terminal:

```
$ php utftest.php
Current PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

&oslash;&aelig;&aring; jeść ясть
```

... which is what I would have expected. But, when I upload this to remote server, and I login to remote server via `ssh`, and execute the same test in terminal, I get this:

```
$ php utftest.php 
Current PHP version: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21

&Atilde;&cedil;&Atilde;&brvbar;&Atilde;&yen; je&Aring;�&Auml;� &Ntilde;Ntilde;�&Ntilde;�&Ntilde;�
```

So, for some reason, on the server, I get a lot more HTML entities, plus some binary characters?

Why does this happen - is it because of differing PHP versions? And how can I get this test script run correctly even on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the answer:

[htmlentities destroys utf-8 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679715/htmlentities-destroys-utf-8-strings)

> htmlentities() takes an optional third argument encoding which defines encoding used in conversion. From PHP 5.6.0, default_charset value is used as default. From PHP 5.4.0, UTF-8 is the default. PHP prior to 5.4.0, ISO-8859-1 is used as the default.

So, indeed, the problem was the PHP version, of sorts; so the fix is to use in `utftempl.txt`:

```
<?php //echo htmlentities( $content );
echo htmlentities( $content , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
?>
```

Then both versions will do everything correctly...

Here is also a modified version of the `utftest.php` with slightly more debug output:

```
<?php

  echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() . "\r\n\r\n";

  $content = file_get_contents("utftest.txt");
  print_r($content);
  echo "\r\nENC1: " . mb_detect_encoding($content) . "\r\n\r\n" ;
  $templateFile = "utftempl.txt";
  ob_start();
  include_once($templateFile);
  $file_output = ob_get_clean();
  print_r($file_output);
  echo "\r\nENC2: " . mb_detect_encoding($file_output) . "\r\n\r\n" ;
  echo htmlentities( "øæå jeść ясть" ) . "\r\n\r\n" ;
  echo htmlentities( "øæå jeść ясть", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . "\r\n\r\n" ;

?>
```